# Prevent white flicker when Cordova app loads

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I'm using Cordova (v6.4.0) and the Splashscreen plugin (v4.0.0)   (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen). I'm posting this here because the github repository doesn't have an issues section and solutions mentioned at [Remove White Flicker after splashscreen phonegap 3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21907673/remove-white-flicker-after-splashscreen-phonegap-3-3) didn't work.

The various splash screen images I set are displaying on both Android and iOS devices. However, on Android devices there is a white flash between the splash screen images and my app loading.

In my Cordova config.xml file, I have the following lines for the splash screen:

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="2000" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
```

I tried disabling the splash screen image from automatically hiding and increasing the delay before the splash screen hides by adding the additional following lines to config.xml:

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
```

Because auto hide is false and the delay is 10 seconds, I should see the static loading image for a full 10 seconds, but on both iOS and Android it only displays for a second or two. I'm guessing that is the root of the problem.

Once auto hide can be disabled, I hoped to manually trigger hiding the splash screen within my app's main init function using:

```
navigator.splashscreen.hide();
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I didn't find a solution.